# ogr2ogr write multiple layers to one geopackage

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, geopackage, shell

I'm using `ogr2ogr` to write a SQL query from PostGIS to a GeoPackage in a linux shell.
Query by Query to many GPKG:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" point.gpkg PG:"host=localhost dbname=data user=user password=*******" -sql "select * from point-features"
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" line.gpkg PG:"host=localhost dbname=data user=user password=*******" -sql "select * from line-features"
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" polygon.gpkg PG:"host=localhost dbname=data user=user password=*******" -sql "select * from polygon-features"
```

I would like to write multiple layers from queries into one GeoPackage, but I cannot find a documentation to this.

Like:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" pointlinepolygon.gpkg pointlayer linelayer polygonlayer PG:"host=localhost dbname=data user=user password=*******" -sql "select * from pointlinepolygon-features"
```

Would be happy about support.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have different SQL statements, so you can't do one single line.

You can do mutiple statements like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" your_gpkg.gpkg PG:"host=localhost dbname=etienne user=postgres password=foo" -nln points -sql "SELECT * FROM points"
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" your_gpkg.gpkg PG:"host=localhost dbname=etienne user=postgres password=foo" -nln lines -update  -sql "SELECT * FROM lines"
```

This will give you 2 layers in the Geopackage:

```
ogrinfo your_gpkg.gpkg 
INFO: Open of `your_gpkg.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.
1: points
2: lines
```

The `-nln` is for specifying the layer name. They need to be different. https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-nln

And `-update` is to open the layer in update mode. https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-update

**Edited**, I first used `-append` and it worked. But as suggested in comment, I have updated the answer to use `-update` which is designed for this.

Comment: If you read the document carefully append does a different thing `Append to existing layer instead of creating new`. I would say that the option that is needed is update https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-update `Open existing output datasource in update mode rather than trying to create a new one`. Did your second command really work for you?

Comment: You are correct. `update` would be better indeed. And yes the second command really works. The OGRInfo that I showed is real. I also tried in QGIS, it's works. I will update my answer, even if it works.

Comment: I did a test myself and you are right. I would have thought that without -update ogr2ogr would delete the old "your_gpkg.gpkg" database and create a new one, so that finally there would be a database with just "lines" layer. I get two layers also into plain sqlite and spatialite outputs so -append seems fire also -update.